# Sharing imports between Python processes

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-import

I am using `multiprocessing` package to spawn multiple processes that execute a function, say `func` (with different arguments). `func` imports `numpy` package and I was wondering if every process would import the package. In fact, the main thread, or rather main process also imports `numpy` and that can be easily shared between different `func` executing processes.

There would be a major performance hit due to multiple imports of a library.

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if every process would import the package.

Assuming the import occurs after you've forked the process, then, yes. You could avoid this by doing the import before the fork, though.

> There would be a major performance hit due to multiple imports of a library.

Well, there would a performance hit if you do the import after the fork, but probably not a "major" one. The OS would most likely have all the necessary files in its cache, so it would only be reading from RAM, not disk.

**Update**

Just noticed this...

> In fact, the main thread, or rather main process also imports `numpy`...

If you're already importing `numpy` before forking, then the imports in the subprocesses will only create a reference to the existing imported module. This should take less than a millisecond, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I am not sure if the processes spawned by `multiprocessing` are sub-processes of the main processes. I always thought they were different processes with a communication channel with the main process. In that case each of them would have their own Python `interpreter` and would need to import the library individually.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni Which OS are you using?

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni You should be fine then. I believe it still spawns its subprocesses using `os.fork()` which makes an identical copy of the parent process. There are some [ongoing discussions](http://bugs.python.org/issue8713) about this behavior which might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that question is in the documentation of the multiprocessing library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods.

The summary is that it depends on which start method you choose. There are 3 methods available (defaults to fork on Unix, to spawn on Windows/Mac):

1. **spawn**: The parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process. **The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run the process object’s run() method**.
2. **fork**: The parent process uses os.fork() to fork the Python interpreter. **The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child process.**
3. **forkserver**: When the program starts and selects the forkserver start method, a server process is started. **From then on, whenever a new process is needed, the parent process connects to the server and requests that it fork a new process**.

You must set the start method if you want to change it. Example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
mp.set_start_method('spawn')
```